# Save text to file shortcut Monterey

Tags: macos, shortcut

I try to create a shortcut for macOS Monterey to export data from Tim (a time tracker) and save that data to a file.

I am able to do the first step (export data), but I have no idea how to do the second step (put the text in a file).

One way could be to use a shell script to export the data:

[image: shortcut app paste input to shell]

But this gives me an almost empty file:

```
$ cat tim.txt
Save text to file%
```

There must be a [better] way to save the data to a text file.

When I try to debug the first step, I get the correct output:

[image: debug information look ok]

How can I save the text to a file (overwrite the file or create the file if it does not exist.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I've found that it is more straightforward than I thought.

[image: save file in shortcut app]

There seems to be a bug (or a IMO bad behaviour) in the shortcuts app, the suffix of the file is always `.txt`, but I prefer `.json`, so I need a third step to rename the file.

The problem I had was to change the directory to the desired output and use a relative filename from there.